# Moq raise event Parameter count mismatch

Tags: events, mocking, moq

I have an interface, with an event I want to fire in a mock:

```
public interface IGpsLocationSource
{
    event EventHandler<GpsLocation> GpsLocationUpdated;
}
```

My test look like this:

```
var gps = new Mock<IGpsLocationSource>();
gps.Raise(x => x.GpsLocationUpdated += (sender, e) => { },  new GpsLocation(0, 0));
```

I get the following error:

Result StackTrace:
at Moq.Mock`1.Raise(Action`1 eventExpression, Object[] args)
   at Test.cs:line 27
Result Message: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot the "sender"

```
gps.Raise(x => x.GpsLocationUpdated += (sender, e) => { }, this, new GpsLocation(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone else, I encountered the "parameter count mismatch" issue in a different scenario. I was raising the event using this syntax:

```
_myMock.Raise(o => o.MyEvent += null, new FoobarEventArgs());
```

It turned out that the event args class you specify here must inherit from `EventArgs`, which mine wasnt. Changing the class to the following solved the issue for me:

```
public class FoobarEventArgs : EventArgs
...
```